# ‘Jenkinsfile’ not found on Multibranch Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, svn, continuous-integration

We moved a repository within our SVN and after adjusting that path accordingly in the Jenkins configuration it's unable to recognize any branches.

I checked that the Jenkinsfiles are indeed there, have no extensions and there is no issue with case-sensitivity. I also tried to create an entirely new configuration, same outcome.

Log output is:

```
[Mon Oct 21 17:17:00 CEST 2019] Starting branch indexing...
Opening conection to svn://vsvn/svn-root/BTR/Control/V2.2_Released/
Checking directory /svn-root/BTR/Control/V2.2_Released@HEAD
Checking directory /svn-root/BTR/Control/V2.2_Released/branches@8827
Checking candidate branch /svn-root/BTR/Control/V2.2_Released/branches/DotNetCoreMigrationPOC@8808
      ‘Jenkinsfile’ not found
Does not meet criteria
Checking candidate branch /svn-root/BTR/Control/V2.2_Released/branches/1.7_IONodeComponentRefactoring@7898
      ‘Jenkinsfile’ not found
Does not meet criteria
Checking candidate branch /svn-root/BTR/Control/V2.2_Released/branches/devcon@7860
      ‘Jenkinsfile’ not found
Does not meet criteria
Checking directory /svn-root/BTR/Control/V2.2_Released/tags@8810
Checking candidate branch /svn-root/BTR/Control/V2.2_Released/trunk@8779
      ‘Jenkinsfile’ not found
Does not meet criteria
[Mon Oct 21 17:17:00 CEST 2019] Finished branch indexing. Indexing took 0.15 sec
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: What’s the URL that you have configured in Jenkins? The log reads `/<<svn url>>/trunk@8779`. Shouldn’t it be `branches` instead of `trunk`?

Comment: As it's a Multibranch Pipeline and thus "searches" for all the branches you've configured. For simplification I just posted the output of for trunk. I've edited the question to show the entire log.

Comment: can you please post the Jenkins job configuration image.

Comment: where do I find it? or do you mean a screenshot of the configuration html?